# store numbers found in a string in a an array with preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I need to detect the number of times numbers are found within a string. If the string is `"1 ssdsdsd 2"` I need an array with `[1,2]` in it. If the string is `"1 a"` I need an array such as: `[1]`.

With my below attempts, I am close, but I end up with duplicate numbers in there. Preg match seems more appropriate for what I need but duplicates matches as well.

Any idea why this is? I appreciate any suggestions on how to accomplish this.

input

```
  preg_match_all("/([0-9]+)/", trim($s), $matches); //$s = "1 2", output below
  //preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", trim($s), $matches); //$s = "1 .", outputs [1,1]
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the capture group,

```
preg_match_all("/[0-9]+/", trim($s), $matches);
```

The first element in matches array is the full match of the regex, the second one is the capture group.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Interesting, can you explain what the capture group is for? it seems like a duplicate entry. Also is it possible to accomplish this with `preg_match()` and not have to remove the capture group (to keep things simpler)?

Comment: `preg_match`matches a single occurrence of the pattern, here you have to use `preg_match_all` because you have 1 **or more** occurrences.  The capture groups is usefull when the regex must match more than the capture group alone , for example `$s = 'abc 123 def 456; $re = '/[a-z]+ (\d+)/'` the regex matches `abc 123` and the capture group contains `123`, (same  for `def 456`)

Answer (score 0):

You can opt to remove all non-digit chars and get the `strlen()`

```
echo strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '1 ssdsdsd 2')); // 2 digits
echo strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '1 ssd324sd567s.d6756 2')); // 12 digits
echo strlen(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '123456789')); // 9 digits
```

If you know that PHP string chars can be accessed by their index position then you can use something like:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '9 ssdsdsd 5')[0]; // outputs 9 because the resulting string is '95' and position zero's value is 9
```

Comment: After removing non digit, how could you distinguish the different numbers?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_split()` is the ideal tool for this job because it will return a flat, indexed array of numbers.

Use `\D+` to explode on one or more occurrences of non-numeric characters. Use the function flag to ensure there are no empty elements in the output array -- this eliminates the need to trim in advance.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/AAiBv))

```
var_export(
    preg_split(
        '/\D+/',
        $s,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
    )
);
```